# Ubuntu 21.10 Broken Boot - Grub 2 Changes Made to Access Bios Infinite Boot no Display (Bricked)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue

So I recently bought a friends old custom PC so I could upgrade it. I switched to Ubuntu 21.10 from Windows 10. It worked well for a few weeks and I was learning about Linux having a good time. However, I could not for the life of me get BIOS to show up with any command whatsoever when booting after doing this install. So I read a few things installed grub but can't say I understood it and in hindsight I should've never done this. I thought BIOS was just this thing you could always access via command without fail I didn't understand the boot process. So what happened is in trying to access this I installed Grub2 I think it's called Grub2 Extensions or something like that. It was a Grub menu on the Ubuntu OS that allowed me to manage my computers boot cycle. I believed at the time that by putting UEFI Firmware Settings as where to boot from I'd be able to get to bios at when booting. I didn't understand the difference or the utility fully at the time and now realize I messed up. My PC boots with no display being detected no video signal is being sent out, and it just restarts itself infinitely. I finally put Ubuntu installation back onto a USB. I also put Grub2 boot helper super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.04s1 on another USB and Boot Repair Dist boot-repair-disk-64bit on another trying to fix this but nothing seems to break the cycle using Rufus. When I use the Ubuntu USB the PC will actually stop the infinite restarts but still no display signal is being sent out. Is it totally bricked? Does anyone understand what I've done here that's broken everything and is there someway I can fix it? I totally went out of my depth here and it was a mistake I'm a lifelong windows user and yeah should've read more. It's been 2 days and nothing going right so I am coming to the community.

Hardware:
(EVGA) Nvidia Geforce RTX 2070 XC 8GB GDDR6
Intel Core i7-8700k 3.7Ghz (4.7Ghz Turbo) w/ Intel UHD Graphics 630
Corsair Vengeance LPX 62Gb RAM
ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-H Gaming Motherboard ATX DDR4 DP HDMI M.2 USB 3.1 Gen2 Gigabit LAN
Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD 500GB M.2 NVMe Interface w/ V-NAND
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500Gb (from what I remember was formatted as a MSDOS master boot drive had no access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bios(or UEFI) has nothing to do with grub. Bios always comes first. It(the bios/UEFI) looks (after its own initialization) at the first partition if there is an operating system. This is where grub comes in.  I would not mess with with grub and its so called extensions - so you did not brick your PC, but you might've bricked your bootloader. Use the stick you've taken for installing your Ubuntu and fix your grub (without any extensions). [This](https://www.fosslinux.com/4477/how-to-repair-the-grub-bootloader-using-a-ubuntu-live-usb-drive.htm) explains how to fix your grub with a live USB -  [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a detailed explanation on how to fix your bootloader with a special boot repair. This has been asked many times in this forum, so I'm not elaborating the steps.

Comment: That's fair. Thank you very much I will read these and proceed.